# Same function for multiple jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the same functions to run for 2 jQuery objects: `$('input[type="text"]')` and `$('textarea[type=text]')`. How can I combine those two in the code below? (currently, only input is included).

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {   
        if (this.value == this.defaultValue){  
            this.value = '';  
        }  
        if(this.value != this.defaultValue){  
            this.select();  
        }  
}); 

$('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {    
        if ($.trim(this.value == '')){  
            this.value = (this.defaultValue ? this.defaultValue : '');  
        }  
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why does your `textarea` have a `type=text`? That is not a valid attribute for a `textarea`

Comment: Didn´t know that. My object is now $('textarea')

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('textarea[type="text"], input[type="text"]').focus(...).blur(...);
```

Similarly you can also use jQuery's [`add`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/add#expr) function:

```
$('textarea[type="text"]').add('input[type="text"]').focus(...).blur(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

May be easier to put a class on it and filter by that.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.clearDefValueOnFocus = function() {
    return this.focus(function(){
        if (this.value == this.defaultValue){  
            this.value = '';  
        }  
        if(this.value != this.defaultValue){  
            this.select();  
        }  
    }).blur(function(){
        if (jQuery.trim(this.value) == ''){  
            this.value = this.defaultValue || '';  
        }  
    });
};

$('input[type="text"]').clearDefValueOnFocus();
$('textarea[type=text]').clearDefValueOnFocus();
```